# CSS List Border Not Filling HTML Div

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar/list that is using only HTML and CSS. The background image for the nav bar is 45px tall.

The list elements have been set with a CSS `border-left` property. I basically want to have a single vertical separator before each item in the list.

When I change the font in the list to around 30px the height of the border-left fills the 45px height of the div which is good. But when I set the size of the font smaller the border-left no longer fills the height of the `div`.

How can I set the font in the list small and yet still have the height of the `border-left` to 45px?

I have placed the code below. Thanks in advance

CSS:

```
#navbar{
    background-image: url('../images/navbar.png');
    color: white;
    font: 25px arial,sans-serif;
    height: 45px;
}
#navbar a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 5;
    padding: 5;
}
#navbar li{
    border-left: solid 1px white;
    display: inline;
    padding: 1px 10px 1px 1px;  
    margin: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="clear" id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">In Jouw Regio</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/bQe6W/1/

I changed the following

```
#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Also set the background of the div to gray so you can see the example!

Comment: this won't work in IE7, however - you could also use display:block + float: left http://jsfiddle.net/CU7NV/1/

Comment: @ptriek... good point, though display: block is implied if you're floating the element, you don't need to specify it.

Comment: @Terminal-Frost interesting, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

For `#navbar li` change the display to `inline-block` and set the `height` to `100%` and set the `line-height` to `45px`.